# Forgot to create a new repo at Bitbucket before creating one at local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am learning RoR from Michael Hartl's tutorial. I created a new repository with git init and continued with:

```
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:ashsean46/sampleapp.git
```

I forgot to initialize a repo at Bitbucket before running this command.
I deployed the app on heroku and continued with the tutorial until this command stumped me:

```
$ git push -u origin statpage
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

(here statpage is my side branch) I have done this mistake before but the repo automatically showed up at Bitbucket after one day. Also I tried running the master branch code on heroku and everything works fine.

Why does this happen?
Is there any way of displaying the created repo at Bitbucket?

Comment: First of all, run `git remote -v` and check it contains same url for your bitbucket repo. You will find two different url for origin and heroku. So, It will work fine for your heroku but if it doesn't contain correct url for origin, so you are facing this problem.  Try to run `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
` with new url of your bitbucket repo . Please refer https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Comment: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: no address associated with name` - looks like a connection issue to me. Can you access Bitbucket via your browser?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. i removed the app altogether(removed the folder plus rm -rf command). will try the approach if I do the mistake again.

Comment: and yes i can open bitbucket and heroku in my browser,

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary-I did the mistake again and tried your way. It worked! Thanks! But now every time I use a command which remotely connects to my git repo eg->git push it asks for my email and password for bitbucket. How do i fix that??